# Don't render X when pictures don't exist QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I have a shape with 2 features and 2 fields: each field represents the path of a picture. The first feature has both field (so 2 pictures) while the second one has just one picture (the second field is NULL).

When I use the map composer combined with the atlas I'd like to export for each feature also the pictures but what I'm trying to do is to not having the red X for the second picture of the second feature:

**first feature with both pictures**

[image]

**second feature with only one picture**
[image]

Is there a way to use the Atlas feature and don't render the picture when the field is NULL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Item Properties tab, check the box next to "Exclude item from exports," and click the "data defined override" button next to it.

[image]

Input this expression:

> CASE WHEN "field" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Substitute the name of your field where it says "field."

Now the image with a null filepath will be excluded when you export the print composer.

---

Note that it will still display with a red X in the print composer itself. If you don't want to see that red X even in the print composer, instead use data-defined override for image transparency with this code:

> CASE WHEN "field" is null THEN 100 END

Comment: hi @csk. Thanks for the answer. Sometimes your suggestion works perfectly sometimes not. So I guess it is something related to my data. Thanks!